# in csv file data is not in proper format show some html code in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Data in csv file is not in proper format it show like as javascript code or html code in only one column

Code in userscontroller

```
for export data in csvfile from database of user table 
    public function export() {
            $this->response->download("export.csv");
    
            $data = $this->Users->find('all');
            $this->set(compact('data'));
    
            $this->layout = 'ajax'; 
    
            return;
        }
    
    // app/Views/Users/export
    
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv");  
    
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        foreach ($row['Users'] as $cell) {
            // Escape double quotation marks
            $cell = '"' . preg_replace('/"/','""',$cell) . '"';
        }
        echo implode(',', $row['Users']) . "\n";
    }
```

Screenshot of output:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, Look like it is debug variable for debug bar or something like that (cause i not have full view of your csv file)
So I can suggest some action to check as i know:

- Check "your template" file as see `$this->layout = 'ajax';` . It may contain default debug bar or custom code. Empty **ajax layout** look like [this](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.x/templates/layout/ajax.php)
- Because CSV file is not normal view. So better you just set this action not use any view layout by using `$this->layout = false;` or in Cake 3 use `$this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);`

Sometime php code also inject to output file or view page because your code have notice or warning message. So please check the full csv file, start read from where **html code** begin and you will understand the problem